# jquery fancyform 1.4.2 plugin, transformSelect() causes my js-handler to stop working on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, fancyform

so I have the following html/js-code, which seems to work fine on desktop browsers(at least IE10+, latest FF/Chrome, which is the targeted audience):

HTML (shown inside colorbox-overlay, using knockout for the bindings):

```
<li>
    <select id="selectPriceType" class="tsel" name="selectPriceType" data-bind="value: priceSetting">
        <option value="hide">Keinen Preis anzeigen</option>
        <option value="line">Preis pro Menülinie</option>
        <option value="calc">Preis pro Menü</option>
    </select>
    <div class="price-type"></div>
    <div class="price-type">
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="menu-price-list" data-bind="foreach: menuLinePrices">
            <div class="menu-line-price">
                <label data-bind="text: text"></label>
                <span>€</span> <input type="text" data-bind="value: price" name="inputpriceline#12776" id="inputpriceline#12776" />
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="price-type">
        <div class="price-space">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Ausgabepreis:</legend>
                <dl>
                    <dt><label class="rb" data-bind="css:{ checked : surcharge() == 'no'}">Ohne Aufschlag<input type="radio" value="no" class="styled-input" data-bind="checked: surcharge" name="surcharge" id="rbtnSurchargeNone" /></label></dt>
                   ...
                </dl>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>MwSt:</legend>
                <label class="rb" data-bind="css:{ checked : vat() == '0'}">keine Angabe<input type="radio" class="styled-input" data-bind="checked: vat" value="0" name="vat"></label>
               ...
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

My JS-Inithandler looks for a variable defined in knockout and should show/hide the html elements based on the value of option ("hide", "line", "calc"):

```
pricetype = {
            init: function () {
                $('#selectPriceType').change(function () {
                    $(this).siblings('.price-type').hide().eq(this.selectedIndex).show();
                    $.colorbox.resize();
                }).change();
            }
        }
```

and it is called like this in my document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            initHelpContents();
            InitPrintCockpit(); //here my variable is set to 'calc'
            printCockpitPageModel.menuplanid('###MenuPlanId###');
            $("select").transformSelect();
            $("a.btn-generic").colorbox({ inline: true, width: "905px", close: "" });
            accordion.init();
            footerNav.init();
            pricetype.init();

            changeSettingHint.init();

            $('.reset').click(function () {
                $('#cboxClose').click();
            });

            // $(document).ready() may execute before css styles are applied and wrong font-family or font-size may result in wrong scrollHeight.
            $(window).load(function () {
                $('#Menue').find('textarea').change();
            })
        });
```

So as said, everything works fine on desktop browsers. But opening this on mobile browsers (tested on ipad / latest safari and android4 / chrome 32 and builtin "browser") leads to weird behaviour. It seems like the whole "init"-part does not get executed. Every div is shown, not just the one I set via knockout. I tried to look for it via chrome debugger tools, but I don't get any output on the console. I also tried to look what is in `this.selectedIndex`, but it's fine, too. Then I tried removing `$("select").transformSelect();` from my document-ready, and "ta-daa", it seems to work like a charm.

I use fancyforms 1.4.2 (http://plugins.jquery.com/Fancyform/ )here, and googling around didn't get me an answer, so I hope some of you guys could help me out here for I am really out of ideas now.